# Checkerboard pattern in iTunes videos

Tags: itunes, video

While watching iTunes-purchased video content (TV/movies), I periodically see a quick flash of the gray/white DRM checkerboard that iTunes shows when you're trying to watch video while screen-sharing.

The gist:

- Mac mini Mid-2012 (10.8.3) with locally-stored iTunes library
- Screen sharing is enabled, but *not* active when this occurs
- Sometimes it's a flicker about one frame in duration
- Sometimes mid-video the checkerboard appears and stays.

  - When this occurs, scrubbing the video back some fixes it.
- It never seems to happen in the same location in a video twice.

I would, of course, appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to keep this from happening. It's really quite jarring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same behavior. If you turn off the Screen Sharing service in System Preferences > Sharing, it will cure the issue. Turning it back on will again present the intermittent flashes of CPHD checkerboard during playback. Must be a bug - gonna call AppleCare and get them to file a bug report.

Comment: Yep, this fixes it. A shame. I'm glad there's a way to remotely enable/disable Screen Sharing in case I leave it off and need to control the machine.